# Android application closes without any message on both screen or LogCat

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've developed an application to exchange small text messages between phones via Bluetooth.

My application works fine for 1 hour or 2 then it suddenly close without any warning both on screen or log-cat. During my tests I tried to exchange messages between 2 phones and I noticed that the applications silently close on them at different times and always without any reason

(I had both phones plugged to my laptop and with log-cat running).

Does Android shut down apps if it thinks that are idle? I send messages every 1-2 minutes.. shall I send them with an higher frequency?

EDIT:

I've noticed another strange behaviour.. sometimes when my app closes I lose all the messagges related to it into logcat.. they got completely wiped.

Comment: Does this happen on some particular devices? Have screen backlight gone off while testing?

Comment: No it quite happens on all the devices that I use in my testbed. Yes, I have screen off during tests

Comment: Is there a chance that onPause() call causes apps to stop (as 'for example, onPause() is called when the device goes to sleep')? Have You tried to keep wake_lock?

Comment: Actually I've left the onPause() methos blank because in this phase of the development I don't need it to do anything when the app is no more visible.